# Textbooks which derive largest usable rate for standard LMS filter?

Tags: adaptive-filters, reference-request, least-squares, lms

Suppose $x$ is sampled from standard 0-centered Gaussian in d-dimensions, and I apply the following iteration.

$$w \leftarrow w-\alpha x \langle w, x \rangle \tag 1$$

What is largest $\alpha$ such that this iteration converges almost surely for any starting $w$? Couple of textbooks I checked solve for $\alpha$ such that $\|w\|$ decreases in expectation, but this rate has little bearing on practical behavior because of infinite variance, looking to catch up on background to analyze the more relevant case.

Actual rate (from [simulations](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/simple-simulation.nb)) is $a\approx 2.42$ for $d=1$ and $a\approx 1$ for $d=2$.

[image]

Comment: The classic "Adaptive Filter Theory" by Simon Haykin contains a section on the "Stability and Performance Analysis of the LMS Algorithm". As is derived there, the maximum step size depends on the correlation properties of the input signal. By the way: What do you mean with "infinite variance"?

Comment: Yes, I skimmed that book, and it seems to derive conservative rates, so in this case it would be 0.667 instead of 2.42. Infinite variance means the variance grows without limit even though you converge almost surely

Comment: You use $\alpha$ in your (1), then $a$ elsewhere.  I assume these are the same?  If so, please edit for consistency.